# How to maintain cucumber test results for each Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I am executing cucumber tests using Jenkins pipeline job(Jenkinsfile). But for every job it is overwriting the existing test results in the target/surefire-reports folder.

I would like to display all the cucumber test results for each and every job.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a *timestamp* in the reports folder name. Try the following code.

```
  <properties>
     <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
     <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
  <properties>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>${masterThougth.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>execution</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                    <projectName>${project.artifactId}</projectName>
                    <buildNumber>${project.build}</buildNumber>
                    <parallelTesting>true</parallelTesting>
                    <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-report/${timestamp}</outputDirectory>
                    <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-report/</cucumberOutput>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the cucumber test result use cucumber report plugin

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Test+Result+Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Reports+Plugin

And detailed configuration of cucumber plugin in jenkins

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Test+Result+Plugin